# How to write a blank line in a config file when adding an app key programatically in .NET?

Tags: c#, xml, app-config

I am writing an app key to an App.Config file programatically using code like below, but I also want to add a blank line for readability inside the App.Config file after writing/saving the key. Is this possible? If so, how? I could not find an answer.

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

config.AppSettings.Settings.Add(appKey, appKeyValue);

// Save the changes in App.config file.
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, unfortunately it's not pleasant. Consider the following, which does add the whitespace:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"app.config");
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
var first = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
doc.DocumentElement.InsertBefore(doc.CreateSignificantWhitespace("\r\n\r\n"), first);
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.NewLineChars = "\r\n";
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"app.config", settings))
{
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```

This unfortunately ignores the `XmlWriterSettings.Indent` setting after the added significant whitespace node and puts all the nodes on a single line. I'm thinking this may be a bug, or else the significant whitespace is opting into an "all-or-nothing" formatting, where you then have to control the complete formatting of the document.

However, if you'd accept a comment node, this works better:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"app.config");
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
var first = doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
doc.DocumentElement.InsertBefore(doc.CreateComment(""), first);
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.NewLineChars = "\r\n";
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"app.config", settings))
{
    doc.Save(writer);
}
```